# Is $\sum_{x=1}^\infty \frac{1}{x B^x} = -\log{\frac{B-1}{B}} $ simply normal in some base $b$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, sequences-and-series, transcendental-number-theory

A real number is said to be simply normal in an integer base $b$ if its infinite sequence of digits is distributed uniformly.

We have the BBP-type formula ([BBP](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BBPFormula.html)
was discovered by Simon Plouffe in 1995)

$$ \sum_{x=1}^\infty \frac{1}{x B^x} = -\log{\frac{B-1}{B}}$$

> Q1 Are there integers $b,B>1$ such that we can show
> $-\log{\frac{B-1}{B}}$
> is simply normal in base $b$ or not simply normal in base $b$?

Limited numerical experiments suggest the logarithm is normal in base $B$.

---

Observe that the series is BBP-type formula and likely
also [Digit-Extraction Algorithm](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Digit-ExtractionAlgorithm.html)

> An algorithm which allows digits of a given number to be calculated without requiring the computation of earlier digits

Comment: This is the natural logarithm?  I would guess it is fully normal in all bases.  But I would also guess that no one knows how to prove even simple normality in any base.  The case $B=2$ is $-\log(1/2) = \log 2$.  Showing that is normal would be a big result!

Comment: You may know about Stoneham numbers. According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stoneham_number for coprime $b,c>1$, the number $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{1\over b^{c^k}c^k}$$ is $b$-normal whenever $c$ is an odd prime and $b$ is a primitive root modulo $c^2$. Bailey and Crandall have the same conclusion, under weaker hypotheses.